# ts-morph - how to insert into existing constructor template within main class

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I am a beginner at TS manipulation with ts-morph.

I have a template of existing source file, and i wanted to continue building up the template within the constructor space within the main class.

**cdk-gen-stack.ts**

```
export class CdkGenStack extends cdk.Stack {
  constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    
    //to insert code below
    
  }
}
```

**ts-morph.ts**

```
import * as tsmorph from "ts-morph";

const project = new tsmorph.Project({
    tsConfigFilePath: "tsconfig.json",
});
const sourceFile = project.getSourceFile("lib/cdk-gen-stack.ts");

const mainClasses = sourceFile?.getClass("CdkGenStack");

const mainConstructor = mainClasses?.getConstructors();

sourceFile?.save();
```

I am stuck as I am not sure what I could do after getting the constructor from the main class. What I want to achieve for example within the main template within the main class and constructor:

**cdk-gen-stack.ts (morphed)**

```
export class CdkGenStack extends cdk.Stack {
    constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        // I want to start inserting something here, for example:
        const table = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'Table', {
            partitionKey: { name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING }
        });

    }
}
```

I have spent a lot of time researching online and trying to get any existing methods I can use with the constructor. There are `addMethods` and `addVariable` for classes, for example `mainClasses?.addMember("test");` or:

```
mainClasses?.set({
    ctors: [{ 
        statements: [
            "test"
        ]
    }]
});
```

However these will insert them outside the constructor. What I want is to insert it within the given `constructor` that already exists in the class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.addStatements` on the constructor node:

```
const mainConstructors = clazz.getConstructors();
mainConstructors[0].addStatements('console.log(123);');
```

Check [the documentation](https://ts-morph.com/manipulation/#adding-inserting-and-removing-statements) for more examples and the API.

Comment: thanks Kelvin, I checked the documentation and tried. The problem is that `getConstructors` doesn't have the method available to use to addStatements. Your code throws an error "Property 'addStatements' does not exist on type 'number[]'.". I tried with `mainConstructor?.addStatements('console.log(123);')` earlier but also "Property 'addStatements' does not exist on type 'ConstructorDeclaration[]'."

Comment: I got the different 'add' or 'insert' methods available in the documentation, but those are for source file or class mainly, I can't be more specific referring to the constructor section as the methods are not available.

Comment: @unacorn Weird, the documentation says that `Statements can be added, inserted, or removed from nodes with a body (ex. functions, methods, namespaces, source files)` so I'd assume constructors too. Make sure you're actually operating on a constructor node. E.g. `mainConstructor` in your example is an array of constructors it seems.

Comment: sorry just to clarify "Make sure you're actually operating on a constructor node" > does that mean to specify `mainConstructor[0]`? If yes yah I tried that too (as well as without). the node as array throws error  "Property 'addStatements' does not exist on type 'number[]'.

Comment: That's a TypeScript error. It thinks your `mainConstructors` is an array of numbers? Not sure what's going on there, might be an issue with typings. Not sure.